# Javascript API polling

Tags: javascript

I have RestAPI endpoint providing simple response with single flag "needUpdate" true/false.

I am trying to write Javascript polling function which calls this endpoint and in case that needUpdate=true, it reloads whole web page.

```js
var url = "https://www.example.com/api";
var needUpdate;

function poll(){
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onload = function(e) {
      if (this.status == 200) {
        const myObj = this.response;
        var needUpdate = myObj["needUpdate"];
        console.log('needUpdate', needUpdate); // console
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
    if(needUpdate == true){
      location.reload(); 
    } else {
      poll();
    }
  }, 3000);
}

var json = JSON.stringify(poll());
```

It calls API every 3 seconds as expected and also states proper value of needUpdate into console. But reload does not happen.
It seems that needUpdate value is actualy undefined on the place where I tried to set a condition.
Can you please help me?

Comment: add you condition after this line `console.log('needUpdate', needUpdate); // console`

Comment: define variable needUpdate outside of  setTimeout function

Answer (score 0):

move condition inside `xhr.onload` function

```js
var url = "https://www.example.com/api";
var needUpdate;

function poll(){
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onload = function(e) {
      if (this.status == 200) {
        const myObj = this.response;
        var needUpdate = myObj["needUpdate"];
        console.log('needUpdate', needUpdate); // console
        if(needUpdate == true){
          location.reload(); 
        } else {
          poll();
        }
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
    
  }, 3000);
}

var json = JSON.stringify(poll());
```